# Contacts created using Google-contacts API are not getting synchronized from an Android device

Tags: google-contacts-api

I have created contacts using google contacts POST API. and I am successfully able to fetch them using GET API.
[Reference](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/?hl=en_US#creating_contacts).

Now, Logged into the same google account from an android device and successfully  synced contacts but the contacts which are created using POST API are not imported in sync.

**Note:**

1. Contacts Created from Android are fetched Successfully using GET API from Web-Client.
2. Contacts Deleted using Delete API are successfully deleted from android device on sync ( both contacts which are created using api or android) and vice-versa.

Can anyone help me by telling how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the below settings. Go to `Settings>Accounts-Google>[your account].` Is Contacts checked on? Also, open the Contacts app, tap `Menu>Settings>Contacts to Display` , and make sure it's set to All.

Comment: yes santhosh, both of these are already correct. and sync is also successful.

Comment: let me explain with example. suppose I have created 3 contacts using POST API. and another 5 contacts from android itself. the GET API is giving all 8 contacts. now, i logged into same google account from another device here I am only getting 5 contacts(created from android).but other 3 contacts created from POST API are not synced.

Comment: Can you see them on [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com) ?

Comment: No santhosh. contacts created using POST are not coming.

Comment: Then how you are fetching the contacts using `GET` request?

Comment: yes, Get API is giving all contacts.

Comment: If `GET` request is giving all contacts then it should be present in your `Google Contacts` . Again check whether the contact is present by searching the contact name.

Comment: GET https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/appcontacts21@gmail.com/full and GET https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/appcontacts21@gmail.com/full/a23a1389e36130 these both are giving those contacts.

Comment: but they are not present in contacts.google.com

Comment: Can you edit your question by posting the response of the `GET` request and the screenshot of your `Google Contacts`?

Comment: Santhosh, I found them https://contacts.google.com/other here.

Comment: Good. The contacts you're creating are storing in Other Contacts.

Comment: but how can I get them imported upon sync from android contacts app.

Comment: yes, they are going into other folder, but i donno why. and how move them in Actual contacts.

Comment: Try creating your contacts in My Contacts

Comment: My contacts, i didnt understand. from API or Android or contacts.google.com. from where?

Comment: In your google contacts

Comment: ya, Created in contacts.google.com

Comment: GET API is also giving it.

Comment: Are you able to create contacts in `My Contacts` using GET request?

Comment: No, If I create using API (POST), contacts are going in Other Contacts

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: yeah, Working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `gContact:groupMembershipInfo` field in your XML request body while creating contacts in order to create contacts in `My Contacts`.

Add the following in your `POST` request

```
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" 
href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/userEmail/base/groupId"/>
```

where `groupId` is **6**  for `My Contacts`.

You can get the GroupId for all the groups by sending an authorized `GET` request to the contact groups feed URL

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{userEmail}/full
```

This request wil give the detail of the Groups.

Refer this for more information [Retrieving_all_contact_groups](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contact_groups)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer